# Expand root nodes in Angular Material Tree

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-material-5

**I know there are available methods for expanding and collpasing all** nodes but I just want to expand the first level of nodes (the root nodes). How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you add ngAfterViewInit to your component you can use the toggle method on your treeControl to expand the node specified by the parameter that toggle takes but depending your set up you may have to  do some extra work to get the node you want to expand. Here is what I did to expand just the first node:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
const subject = this.dataSource._flattenedData
subject.subscribe((data) => {
  this.treeControl.toggle(data[0])      
})
}
```

If you wanted to expand a specific node you could dig through that data returned from the subscribe but just make sure to not try to grab things before they have been received by the subscribe or have some conditions to catch for that. Here is what I did to expand all the nodes under the first node as well:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
const subject = this.dataSource._flattenedData
subject.subscribe((data) => {
  this.treeControl.toggle(data[0])
  if(data[1]){
    let i = 1
    while (data[i].level != 0) {
      this.treeControl.toggle(data[i++])
    }
  }      
})
}
```